# Heat transfer in fission nuclear reactors

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

In a nuclear fission reactor, the fissile material and the water that is heated up are separated by a physical barrier. That barrier would allow for the transfer of heat via radiation (of photons) and conduction, but neutrons also escape the fission region to be absorbed by the water. What is the relative contribution of these processes to the heat transfer from the fissile material to the water?

Comment: A fission event releases about 180 MeV. Prompt neutrons (~2.5 per fission) have around 2 MeV each. And not all escape, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the thermal power comes from the fuel pellets: the fission products whose path is very short, lose their kinetic energy in the fuel itself, they do not cross the zircaloy sheath.
Here is a conventional distribution of fission energy ( total energy : approx 200 MeV ):

- energy of fission products: 169 MeV (in fuel pellets)
- energy prompt neutrons: 5 MeV (in water)
- energy of delayed neutrons: 7.4 keV (in water)
- energy of prompt gammas: 6.6 MeV (in water)
- energy of delayed gammas: 6.3 MeV (in water)
- beta energy: 6.5 Mev (approx half pellets, half water)
- neutrino energy: 8.7 MeV (escaping from the reactor)